# Not able to identify a lenghty linktext in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to identify an element by linktext, I am facing strange issue 
If the linktext value is short i.e `addFirst`, `addLast` will be able to locate the element by using

```
driver.findelement(By.linktext("addLast, addFirst")).click
```

IF the linktext is `addmanualreferraltocheckthelenghtF`, `addmanualreferraltocheckthelenghtF` lengthy as above not able to identify the element

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Can you please paste the HTML code snippet for lengthy link texts and also code that you tried for the respective link texts?

Comment: @ TDHM Sorry It is confidential to share the HTML Code ,                                                                                  <b class="ng-binding">LastName5370a5207086cc99001b50d2, FirstName5370a5207086cc99001b50d2</b> if the link text is long like this I am not able identify by driver.findelement(By.linktext("LastName5370a5207086cc99001b50d2, FirstName5370a5207086cc99001b50d2")).click , Partiallink text command able to identify the element , not bylinktext

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try partial link text.

```
 driver.findelement(By.partialLinkText("addLast, addFirst")).click
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, it worked, but I may create ambiguity in future if the similar linktext exist,

Answer (score 0):

try out contains method. use the XPATH value and in XPATH use contains for link text.

EG:

.//*[contains(@Linktext, "addmanualreferraltocheckthelenghtF")]

driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@Linktext, "addmanualreferraltocheckthelenghtF")]").click

Alternatively you can also use starts with XPATH value.

.//*[starts-with(@linktext,'addmanual')]

driver.findelement(By.xpath("
//*[starts-with(@linktext,'addmanual')]").click

Hope it helps you.